# Segmentation fault for calling base class variable

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, clang, llvm

I have been using this code for a long time now in a project. However, I have recently added `llvm-config --cxxflags --libs` to the compiler in order to link with llvm libraries and it started generating seg faults. I have located the error and it happens when I call base class's variables.

Here is a small example of what I a doing
in Literals.hh

```
class LiteralObj : public RuleObj {

public:

  LiteralObj();
  LiteralObj(char *str);
  ~LiteralObj();
  std::string raw_value;

  static int literalobj_cnt;
  int literalobj_id;
};

class LiteralIntObj : public LiteralObj{

public:

  LiteralIntObj();
  LiteralIntObj(char *str);
  ~LiteralIntObj();
  
  void graphVis(std::ofstream &ofs, std::string &srcRef);

  CODE_GENERATION;
  
  int value;
};
```

Literals.cc

```
LiteralObj::LiteralObj() : RuleObj(){
  ENTER_STATEMENT

    raw_value = "";

    literalobj_id = literalobj_cnt;
    literalobj_cnt++;

}

LiteralObj::LiteralObj(char *str) : RuleObj(){
    ENTER_STATEMENT
    std::cerr << ruleobj_id << "\n";
    raw_value     = str;
    literalobj_id = literalobj_cnt;
    literalobj_cnt++;
}

LiteralObj::~LiteralObj()
{
  ENTER_STATEMENT;
}

LiteralIntObj::LiteralIntObj() : LiteralObj()
{
   ENTER_STATEMENT;
   value = 0;               
}
LiteralIntObj::LiteralIntObj(char *str) : LiteralObj(str)
{ 
  
  ENTER_STATEMENT; 
  std::cerr << ruleobj_id << '\n';
  value = stoi(raw_value);
}

LiteralIntObj::~LiteralIntObj()
{
  ENTER_STATEMENT;
}

void LiteralIntObj::graphVis(std::ofstream &ofs, std::string &srcRef) {
  ENTER_GRAPHVIS;

  // -- define names
  std::string currRef  = "LiteralIntObj";
  std::string name     = "LiteralInt";

  std::cerr << raw_value << "\n";
  //it crashes here with SEGFAULT.

}
```

The code prints out raw_value of the base class fine for the first object, but, when the second is called SEGMENTATION Fault is generated.

Comment: please create and post a [mre]

Comment: Sounds like a stdlib mismatch to me

Comment: Segmentation fault upon accesing member variables in a function can mean that you called said function on an invalid pointer or reference. Another reason why we need a [mre]

Comment: This is the minimum I could reduce the code. I am working in a huge problem could you speciy what exactly you need me to share ?

Comment: Try to remove code until the problem disappears, chance is you will find the error while doing so. If your code is to large it's the best time to learn how to use debugger. Set a breakpoint in `graphVis` and check what actually happens there.

Comment: Oh when i remove `std::cerr << raw-value << '\n' ;` the problem dissapears

Comment: I found out something new. When I print out the pointer usign `this` I get 0xfffffffff. Well problem is clear but how can I solve it?

Comment: Use your debugger to trace the call, check where the faulty pointer or reference comes from.

Comment: I have traced where this faulty pointer comes from and here it is `if (literal_int      ) literal_int      ->graphVis(ofs, currRef);`. As I mentioned in previous comments when I did not use `llvm-config --cxxflags --libs` the pointer was 0 and now it is 0xffffffff...

Comment: Thanks I have solved the problem. It turns out in the constructor I did not set ltieral_int to NULL when I was supposed to do so. Therefore, when I changed the way I compiled the code It was set to something else by default. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i changed compile options the pointers were set to 0xfffffff by default instead of 0. Therefore the check `if (pointer)` generated true even when the pointer were not initialized that led to calling function `graphViz()`.

Comment: That's some crazy settings you have there :D